# How do you create partially pre-filled forms with Rails, Simple_Form, and Cocoon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I have a form to collect CV information from Users. In it, I need to gather what languages they speak and their proficiency level with each. I want to have 3 languages that are required, already present on the form, and have the option to allow the User to add additional languages. Cocoon works great for allowing them to add languages on their own, but, how can I get 3 language instances already in the form?

#### cvs/_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for(@cv, url: user_cvs_path) do |f|

    ...

    %hr
    .row
      %strong Please indicate known languages and ability level in each:
      #languages
        = f.simple_fields_for :languages do |language|
          = render 'language_fields', f: language
        .links
          = link_to_add_association 'Add Language', f, :languages, class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm'

    ...
```

#### cvs/_language_fields.html.haml

```
.row.nested-fields
  = f.input :name, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-4' }
  = f.input :read, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
  = f.input :write, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
  = f.input :speak, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
  = f.input :listen, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove Language", f
```

In it's present state, this section of the form looks like this:
[image: Form showing only the Add language link]

But what I want is this:
[image: Form with three languages already added to the form]

Based on Pablo's answer, I've added this to my controller:

```
def new
  @cv = @user.build_cv
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'English')
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'Cantonese')
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'Mandarin')
end
```

That get's me this far:
[image: Form with three languages added but it still has remove language links]
Now I just need to figure out how to make the languages 'Fixed' so they can't be changed and I need to get rid of the "Remove Language" links that Cocoon supplies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create three languages in the controller:

```
def new
  @cv = @user.build_cv  #or current_user.build_cv
  3.times do { @cv.languages.build }
end
```

To get 3 specific languages, use this in the controller instead:

```
def new
  @cv = @user.build_cv
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'English')
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'Cantonese')
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'Mandarin')
end
```

Then to display those three in the form, make them non-editable and non-removable, change the form to this:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :languages do |language|
  .row
    = language.input :name, disabled: true, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-4' }
    = language.input :read, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
    = language.input :write, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
    = language.input :speak, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
    = language.input :listen, collection: @language_levels, wrapper_html: { class: 'col-sm-2' }
.links
  = link_to_add_association 'Add Language', f, :languages, class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm'
```

Comment: I ended up having to do this in order to get the names pre-filled, but, I think I am going to need to come up with something more complicated. I want to get rid of the "Remove Language" link as well and preferably also set it so they can't change the language. Your answer definitely got me on the right path, though. Thank you.
`def new
  @cv = @user.build_cv
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'English')
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'Cantonese')
  @cv.languages.build(name: 'Mandarin')
end`

Comment: You are right. I didn't read users could have more than one CV and I associated languages to the user, but you got the idea :). That's ok.

Comment: I figured it out. I edited your answer with the solution and marked it as 'Answered'. Thank you for your help!